# Can't integratie rrule js

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, rrule

I am trying to use rrule js:

https://jakubroztocil.github.io/rrule/
https://github.com/jakubroztocil/rrule

But I can't get it to work at all. How has this script to be used in a regular web project?

I've integrated the script as mentioned on github but it fails at the first line and throws a js error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {

Comment: Please define "_a regular web project_".

Comment: Show the code you tried, since if it throws at the first line, it sounds like you did not include it correctly. Are you, for example, trying to run the typescript code directly in the browser without transpiling it? That would cause syntax errors. Or are you trying to run the module on a browser that does not natively support import/export syntax? That would also cause syntax errors.

Comment: @shilly yeah that may be the problem. Actually i have no idea what typescript is. The library says JS so i thought this is some advanced JS syntax that i've never seen before.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/4q2sd0xk/